# I can't retrieve GET parameters in Laravel on Nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I'm using `GET` method, and parameters can be parsed by the URL like so:  `http://path?param1=123&param2=456`. In localhost, I can use `Input::all()` to get data from form. but on my server, which uses nginx as webserver, I get nothing from `Input::all()`

This my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I'm confused as to the error is coming from Laravel or my Webserver.

This my nginx conf

```
server {
        listen   8080; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/path;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;            
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Everything works fine in Apache.

Comment: can you past your nginx conf file

Comment: I have been add the conf, i think this problem is in .ht access or nginx, because in apache all is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your nginx conf like this:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/path;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

After that remember to restart the nginx server: `sudo service nginx restart`